# Remember my revision history diff preference, please

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, diff

Could we implement something like this?

> [image]

(**Note**: That "big" orange box does not need to be there, it's just an example of how it *could* look like.)

I prefer the side-by-side diffs, and I'd like it if it could be saved forever. Right now, I have to select it every time I look at a revision history.

Comment: Agreed, except for the giant orange box

Comment: Yeah, it just needs to remember what you clicked last. The orange box is [stopping the proceedings.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/09/unnecessary-dialogs-stopping-the-proceedings-with-idiocy.html)

Comment: okay, it was just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is implemented in the next build; both for suggested edits and for the revision list (independently of each other).